# How do I give multiple users access to Magento 2 on local host

Tags: magento2, server-setup

I have deployed Magento2, phpmyadmin and XAMPP on a dedicated localhost server running WIndows 10. Everything is working fine and I have uploaded my entire catalogue etc.

I want to give other members of my team access to Magento 2 so they can familiarise themselves with it before I deploy to a production environment.

What is the process I need to go through to give them access once I have edited their permissions?

Comment: Permission means .. you want to create their separate admin account ?

Comment: Yes: I want them to access the store and Admin page under the user access I will set up. I want them to run a lot of tests I have created before I set up my Production environment. I just dont know how to make Magento2 visible  on their machines.

Comment: Okay it is installed on your localhost. If you all are connected on LAN then you need to set up magento with base URL with LAN IP address and share the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the development site is fully configured with a domain name ex. testsite.dev then all the other people wanting to access it need to:

1. Be on the same LAN network. (192.168.x.x)
2. Have admin access on their machines.

What you would do is find your LAN ip and tell them to set a key in the hosts file on their machine that looks like `<your lan ip> testsite.dev www.testsite.dev`
At that point, if you have no firewall blocking port 80/8080/443 they should be able to go to testsite.dev and see the site.

You can get your lan ip address in windows 10 by running `ipconfig` in cmd.

[Info about IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#IPv4_addresses)
[Info about hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file))

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.